# parse5 SAXParser: pipe into a readable stream converted from string

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to use Parse5's SAXParser to pipe into a readable stream that was generated from a string.

Here is my code:

```
        var parse5 = require("parse5");
        var parser = new parse5.SAXParser();
        var stream = require('stream');
        var s = new stream.Readable();
        s.push('text');
        s.push(null);
        parser.on('text', function (res: any) {
            console.log(res);
        });
        s.pipe(parser);
```

I set a break point in the callback function, but it is never hit. Does anyone know what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are misinterpreting the meaning of 'text' event. The [docs](http://inikulin.github.io/parse5/classes/saxparser.html) say:
[image]

The 'text' content here is HTML text content. Perhaps this example will make it more clear for you:

```
[fedora@myhost ~]$ cat example.js

var parse5 = require("parse5");
var parser = new parse5.SAXParser();
var stream = require('stream');
var s = new stream.Readable();
s.push('<h1>text1<h1><h2>text2</h2>');
s.push(null);

parser.on('text', res => {
    console.log(res);
});

s.pipe(parser);

[fedora@myhost ~]$ node example.js
text1
text2
```